# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError for a Minecraft Server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

Recently I tried to upgrade my Minecraft server to a newer version of the game, when I ran it it gave me this error:
`Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.minecraft.bundler.Main java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`

I tried upgrading and downgrading my java version expecting it to fix the problem but nothing seems to work.